# How to parse the value in quotes in an xml tag in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Let us say I have an xml tag like:

```
<test val="val1 ">Test XML</test>
```

I want to parse the value "val1" whenever `<test>` tag occurs in the file so that I can save it to an array.

Comment: Step #1: pick an XML library. I suggest using one that supports XPath/XQuery .. (keywords are thus: "java library xml xpath")

Comment: [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) is a good parsing library

Comment: Your question is tagged with dom. So, do you want to use dom? Have you read its javadoc? What don't you understand in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the XML from the file and select all elements with tag name `test` and extract attribute value from it.

Basically:

`doc.getElementsByTagName("test")` in order to select all `"test"` elements, and for each element found you can select its attribute named `"val"` with `node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("val")` and from this one, if not null just `getTextContent()` to take its text content.

---

A sample code could be something like:

```
// temporary result list just to store the values found
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<document><test val=\"val1\">Test XML</test><test val=\"val2\">Test XML</test><test val=\"val3\">Test XML</test></document>".getBytes()));
// you could use something like: documentBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream("fileName.ext")); instead

// get test nodes and iterate over it checking test attribute
NodeList elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("test");
for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = elements.item(i);
    Node attribute = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("val");
    if (attribute != null) {
        result.add(attribute.getTextContent());
    }
}

// get result values in a string array (if collection is preferred use result instead)
String[] array = result.toArray(new String[] {});

// just print it in a readable format
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

This will print:

```
[val1, val2, val3]
```

Comment: Ok so getattributes().getNamedItem() is what is necessary.

Comment: yes, this will take all attributes and from the attributes the one named `"val"` on this case

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was trying to figure out.Now I just wanted to whether libraries would make it easier to parse the file or the usual dom model would do the job?In terms of memory consideraations if I am parsing a big value

Comment: well you can use a lot of libraries, one I personally like very much is [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net) its [API](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/) is really intuitive and easy to learn (specially when you already used DOM)

Comment: Fair enough.Thank you for you answer.

Comment: If you're asking whether using DOM is a good idea, the answer is no. There are other tree models of XML (JDOM and XOM for example) that are much easier to use, and faster. The only reason people use DOM is (a) it comes with the JDK, and (b) it's perceived as a standard.